# How can I train an SVM classifier with leveldb datatype, generated from caffe framework?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm, caffe

I've fed a bunch of images to the caffe framework (AlexNet) and the last feature descriptors have been extracted and stored in LEVELDB. Now, I want to train a linear SVM classifier on these descriptors. Therefore, I'm wondering to know whether there is any way to train the SVM with LEVELDB data or not. 
Thanks

EDIT:
Working with [this tool](https://github.com/jostosh/caffe-utils) solved the problem

Comment: why do you save to leveldb? try and save to hdf5 instead, then you can use `h5py` module to read hdf5 in python.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The problem is that caffe produces the intermediate features in leveldb  format already.

Comment: have you tried using hdf5 output data layer?

Comment: Yeah, that would an alternative solution ,but the in link I introduced above solved the problem completely.

Comment: @Shai how did you assume the OP wants to use Python for SVMs? In any case, you can use the python bindings to interact directly with lmdb. https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/